# list certificates in the namespace using kubernetes python cli

Tags: python, ssl, kubernetes, certificate

How to *list all* certificates & make a *describe* in the particular namespaces using [kubernetes python cli](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/tree/release-18.0)?

```
# list certificates
kubectl get certificates -n my-namespace

# describe a certificate
kubectl describe certificate my-certificate -n my-namespace
```

Comment: Which Kubernetes version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes by default doesn't have a kind `certificate`, you must first install [cert-manager's](https://cert-manager.io/docs/) `CustomResourceDefinition`.

Considering the above means that in Kuberentes Python client we must use [custom object API](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/8a36dfb113868862d9ef8fd0a44b1fb7621c463a/kubernetes/client/api/custom_objects_api.py), especially in your case: functions `list_namespaced_custom_object()` and `get_namespaced_custom_object()`.

Below code has two functions, one is returning all certificates (equivalent to the `kubectl get certificates` command), the second one is returning information about one specific certificate (equivalent to the `kubectl describe certificate {certificate-name}` command). Based on [this example code](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/8a36dfb113868862d9ef8fd0a44b1fb7621c463a/examples/namespaced_custom_object.py):

```py
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config()
api = client.CustomObjectsApi()

# kubectl get certificates -n my-namespace
def list_certificates():
    resources = api.list_namespaced_custom_object(
        group = "cert-manager.io",
        version = "v1",
        namespace = "my-namespace",
        plural = "certificates"
    )
    return resources

# kubectl describe certificate my-certificate -n my-namespace
def get_certificate():
    resource = api.get_namespaced_custom_object(
        group = "cert-manager.io",
        version = "v1",
        name = "my-certificate",
        namespace = "my-namespace",
        plural = "certificates"
    )
    return resource
```

Keep in mind that both functions are returning [Python dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp).